# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" when trying to open Review Queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

While trying to open the review queues, I get the below error:

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

Answer (score 7):

Yep, this is my bad - see [this MSE post for an apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284387/review-failing-on-se-sites-but-not-so/284389#284389).

Comment: That cat should have been much more fierce looking :)