# Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

Whenever I edit any question on Stack Overflow for the Android tag, it shows a message above the question like this.

[image]

And when I click on peer reviewed, it gives the error:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

like this...

[image]

Stack Overflow shows the error for every edited question since today morning. Why is this error generated?

Comment: Very likely related to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334177/oops-something-bad-happened-when-trying-to-open-review-queues), a bug with the review queues, which suggested edits used. To confirm, see if it is now fixed.