# Oops! Something Bad Happened (SO questions outage)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

## Stack Exchange Bug (<s>in progress</s> RESOLVED - see bottom of post)

[image]

It seems that whenever I try and access a question, I get an error message. Any updates from the community team on this? Every now and then, a page works, but most times, it just hangs and comes up with the error message.

[Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990891) an example, and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421775/css-i-want-a-div-to-be-on-top-of-everything) example.

Also, this happened. It's literally just plain text (*We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault.** Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.*) with `text/html` mimetype, no style or anything:

[image]

Also relevant, Puzzling.SE temporarily dropped out (although it appears to be back as of time of writing).

## Edit 1

[Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) is also down. No other sites confirmed yet.

The outage seems to affect users in the US and Western Europe (France). Others in India report the site is working just fine.

## Edit 2

There seems to be a bit more to the error than just location. It is affecting people in close regions differently. The only exception is India. All users reporting from India say that the site works fine.

Puzzling.SE keeps going up and down as well.

## Edit 3

The issue is resolved, see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384622/) from Mark Henderson explaining more about it.

I really don't think this question is a duplicate of the claim; to quote Adriaan, who put it perfectly:

> not really a duplicate. Yes, the same error message occurred, but these were different issues, at different times, solved in different ways

Comment: Could you share a link where this happens? I clicked through several question on the main page and can't reproduce.

Comment: On [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990891). It hangs and then eventually loads the error page.

Comment: Not an error for me. The page is working absolutely fine

Comment: I am also seeing the error, happens on any SO page

Comment: And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421775/css-i-want-a-div-to-be-on-top-of-everything).

Comment: Oddly, doesn't seem to happen on Meta.

Comment: Each of the SO sites will be a separate service so makes sense that it only affects one of them.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Refreshing the page just shows the error again. All that's in the browser console is the `500` error representing some sort of server-side error. I don't know why someone downvoted - this is legitimately happening.

Comment: Yeh it's up to them to fix and I am sure they are, just have to wait.

Comment: @connectyourcharger [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421775/9819031) also works fine for me.

Comment: That's so weird... I don't know why it works for some and not for others. Maybe it's a location thing (like one server for one section of the US is out)?

Comment: I have the same problem as @connectyourcharger

Comment: I am in India so I think not a problem for me. Also I checked with two different IP addresses- one with cellular data and another wifi.

Comment: I've checked by VPN, maybe the servers in the US is down right now!

Comment: I'm in France with the same problems :/

Comment: My page is opening fine. I think, it is either user specific, or server specific error. probably, you are getting one, because server cashing the files has undergone some changes or maintenance, you will eventually get redirected to different one or it will get resolved in sometime. Yesterday, I had issue with uploading image and updating my info. But it got resolved quickly.

Comment: I have the same issue, however the site is loading just fine using [this](https://www.vpnbook.com/webproxy) web proxy.

Comment: Austria with no problem. Not sure if location is really the key factor.

Comment: Probably a single server in the webfarm that decided to go haywire.

Comment: Reproduced from my end here in Israel.

Comment: I'm on Virgin Media in the UK and have been getting this error all morning. It doesn't happen when I connect to a VPN and access stack overflow that way. I know that years ago stack overflow updated their DNS settings and it took virgin media months to reset their rules. I would add that I am connecting through a VPN also located in the UK.

Comment: Affected in Bangalore, India. Error during 17:00 to 17:15 +5:30 GMT. Now back to normal

Comment: Happend to me 10:00-11:30 at least in Switzerland. Back up now.

Comment: I didn't see a single error from Finland and I've been pretty much browsing Stack Overflow questions for last 5 hours.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I'm not sure what's going on and I'm not able to fix it but I'm getting someone who can to see what's up. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Oops! Something Bad Happened!" when trying to open Review Queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334177/oops-something-bad-happened-when-trying-to-open-review-queues)

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName not really a duplicate. Yes, the same error message occurred, but these where different issues, at different times, solved in different ways.

Comment: Please don't close bug reports that have been fixed. That's not what this close reason is for.

Comment: ["The intrusion originated on May 5..."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/17/update-to-security-incident-may-17-2019/) I wonder if the connection limit was exceeded due to the attacker trying to brute-force something...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We had one web server that ran out of pooled connections to the SQL server. That server serves all of the Stack Exchange websites, so it could have affected any of our properties.

It's all back to normal now.

As the error message says: yes, we even try to fix some of them.